# Need to copy only the last few characters of a string and automatically move to the first empty row before copying data

Tags: excel, vba

This is a two part issue:

1. `.Range("A16").Copy Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1)
   .Range("A13").Copy Sht.Cells(i + 1, 2)
   .Range("A14").Copy Sht.Cells(i + 1, 3)`

This currently copies the entire content of one cell to another. I need only the last few characters (varies for each row).

2. Everytime I run the macro, data is copied back to the beginning of the sheet. This sheet helps populate other sheets, and therefore I need to keep old data. How do I move to the first empty row before pasting any data when I run the macro?

Here's my code
` 
   Option Explicit

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyFolder = "C:\Users\max\Desktop\"

Set Sht = Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Sheets("Log")

'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
i = 1
'loop through directory file and print names
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "csv" Then
        'print file name

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
        Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

        With WB
            For Each ws In .Worksheets
                Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name

                With ws
                    .Range("A16").Copy Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1)
                    .Range("A13").Copy Sht.Cells(i + 1, 2)
                    .Range("A14").Copy Sht.Cells(i + 1, 3)
                End With
                i = i + 1
            Next ws
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    End If
Next objFile

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

`
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Right(.Range("A16").Value, 3)
```

Start on next empty row:

```
i = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: `Sht.Rows.Count`

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. You're a legend!